# Spring Boot : How to get Application name in Spring Boot Executable?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-integration

I have created a Spring boot application and executing the same as a an init.d service.

Tutorial Followed : https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/deployment-install.html#deployment-initd-service

I have multiple symlink created in the same machine like worker-node1, worker-node2, worker-node3, worker-node4 etc so that i can run multiple instances of the same application in the same machine as independent processes. Is there any way to get the symlink name in the Spring boot application so that i can send which worker-node picked up a task to the job management server?

Any help on this regard would be helpful.